# Check Regular expression by Textbox in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have one textbox in which I am entering decimal value like decimal(6,3).
If criteria doesn't match, it should restrict a user from entering value. I am using following code to check on keypress/keydown event.

```
try
{
    string temp = tbweight.Text;
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(temp, @"^\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,3})?$") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbweight.Text))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

but I am not getting last inserted character in temp as last character is still not filled in textbox.

If I use same code on Textchange event, I could not prevent by entering value. I could not use tryparse also because we could not prevent from entering value in textbox by that.

Is any good solution for this?

Comment: Use keyup event not keydown if you want to do it like this

Comment: Use a MaskedTextBox.

Comment: may be 3 ways to do if this is for a Asp.net WEBApp, 1) follow @CodeCaster 's comment, 2) use jquery validate, 3) use ajax and check your condition from a webservice (only in case when there is a complicated validations done in SAP or AX)

Comment: @Vajura: sorry Keyup does not work with e.handled= true;

Comment: @IsaiyavanBabuKaran: sorry, I forget to mention. it is winform application

Comment: Thank you for advising for masktextbox. it would work for me:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private bool dot = false;
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if (System.Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == 8 || e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == 13)
  {
    if (e.KeyChar == '.')
    {
      if (!dot)
      {
        dot = true;
        e.Handled = false;
      }
      else
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
      e.Handled = false;
    }
  }
  else if (e.KeyChar == ',')
  {
    e.Handled = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Handled = true;


    e.Handled = Validate(textBox1.Text, e);

}
private static bool Validate(string p, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    bool valid = false;

    try
    {


        if (System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator == e.KeyChar.ToString())
        {
            // e.Handled = true;
            valid = false;
        }
        else
        {
            string t = string.Format("{0}{1}", p, (e.KeyChar));

            if (!(Regex.IsMatch(t, @"^\d{1,3}(\.\d{0,3})?$") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t)))
            {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    return valid;
}
```